# Understanding nonlocal in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scoping, python-nonlocal

I am trying to understand Python 3 variable scoping and `nonlocal`.

Consider the following function (it is just an example):

```
def build_property(something):

    def deco(func):

        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, something)

        def setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, something, value)

        return property(getter, setter)

    return deco
```

This works fine without `nonlocal`. But if now I want to conditionally create getters and setters depending on `something` I need nonlocal.

```
def build_property(something):

    def deco(func):

        nonlocal something # This is needed

        if something.startswith('A'):
            getter = None
        else:
            def getter(self):
                return getattr(self, something)

        if something.startswith('B'):
            setter = None
        else:
            def setter(self, value):
                setattr(self, something, value)

        return property(getter, setter)

    return deco
```

Why is `nonlocal` needed in one case, but not in the other? In other word, why `something` if correctly found in the first case (without `nonlocal`), but in the second I get: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'something' referenced before assignment" if `nonlocal` is not present?

Comment: ... and your question is? You did *not* say anything about errors/unexpected behaviour. If you get an exception provide the **full** traceback in your question. If you see an unexpected behaviour you *should* provide 1) the behaviour you expect and 2) the actual output you get. We are **not** fortune-tellers.

Comment: Just out of cuiosity: What is the point of your decorators? You don't seem to use `func` anywhere...

Comment: BTW, I didn't test the code, but I don't see why it should be needed in the 2nd case, as `something` is never assigned to...

Comment: It is simply not true that `nonlocal` is required in such a case. `nonlocal` is necessary only when you assign to `something`.

Answer (score 5):

**First:**  `nonlocal` is not necessary in the code you've written. You're not changing the object that `something` points to.

**Second:** There are cases where you would need to use `nonlocal`. Below is some code where `nonlocal` is necessary. Note that all of the assertions are correct (That is, they do not raise an AssertionError).

```
def main():
    variable = 1

    def function():
        variable = 2
    function()
    assert variable == 1

    def function():
        nonlocal variable
        variable = 2
    function()
    assert variable == 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Third:** The code you've presented does not produce the error that you claim it does. If I remove the `nonlocal` line, and call the following functions, I get no errors.

```
build_property('A')(lambda: True)
build_property('B')(lambda: True)
build_property('C')(lambda: True)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def A(d):
    outer = object()
    d["outer"] = outer
    def B():
        print locals()
        assert d["outer"] is outer #This fails and never reaches
        inner = object()
        d=dict()                   #this line.
        print locals()
    def C():
        print locals()
        assert d["outer"] is outer #This goes on fine.
        inner = object()
        print locals()
    return B,C

=> b,c = A(dict())
=> c()
-snip, AOK-
=> b()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment
```

I'm sorry, I deserve the flame. Above code I wrote up quickly, makes the answer that was previously here a bunch of nonsense.

But it's surprising. I always thought of python(2.x) as a completely foresight-less language, evaluating everything at the last moment...

Sorry for what now is off-topic.

Comment: I wrote some stupid things, but it's about keeping references of parent scopes, yeah.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `nonlocal` is not an optimization, it is necessary to correctly identify the scope in which the variable is to be created. Python 2 doesn't keep all the enclosing locals, only those that are referenced by the closure - exactly like Python 3. The difference is that Python 3 allows you to *change* the value of the closed-over variable without creating a new variable as a side effect. `nonlocal` tells the compiler that, despite the assignment happening in an inner block, the variable being modified is the one created in the outer block.